# react-hook-form: unregister doesnt clear component value

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-hook-form

i have one text field which i am manually unregistering. it is successfully getting unregister and data is excluded from formdata, however user entered value still stays in the text field. i am expecting value also get cleared from component as well. i even tried

`setValue('fieldName',"")`

is not working. not sure if i am doing something wrong.
so if i re register my text field and trigger validation, you will see required field validation but value is still present in text field

code below:

```
const App = () => {
  const { register, handleSubmit, unregister, errors, setValue } = useForm();

  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    alert(JSON.stringify(data));
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    register("person.firstName", { required: true });
    register("person.lastName", { required: true });
    // }
  }, [register]);

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <label>First Name</label>
      <input
        type="text"
        name="person.firstName"
        onChange={(e) => setValue("person.firstName", e.target.value)}
      />
      {errors?.person?.firstName && <p> First name required</p>}
      <label>Last Name</label>
      <input
        type="text"
        name="person.lastName"
        onChange={(e) => setValue("person.lastName", e.target.value)}
      />
      {errors?.person?.lastName && <p> Last name required</p>}
      <button
        type="button"
        onClick={() => {
          setValue("person.lastName", "");
          unregister("person.lastName");
        }}
      >
        unregister lastName
      </button>
      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
  );
};
```

here is my [CSB](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-unregister-v6-forked-19446?file=/src/index.js)

i would appreciate any help

Answer (score 1):

the error occurs because you apply your register at useEffect:

```
useEffect(() => {
  register("person.firstName", { required: true });
  register("person.lastName", { required: true });
  // }
}, [register]);
```

instead, if you apply to `ref` at your `input` fields `setValue("person.lastName", "")` will clear the field as expected:

```
<input
  ref={register({ required: true })}
  type="text"
  name="person.firstName"
  onChange={(e) => setValue("person.firstName", e.target.value)}
/>
```

Comment: thx buxatto,  yes it works if i specify ref directly at input, however its not my use case, based on some condition i have to register a field,not always. thanks once again for the reply